# Get File Size on FTP Server and put it on a Label

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ftp, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I'm trying to get the size of a file that is hosted on a `FTP` Server and put it in a `Label` while the `BackgroundWorker works in the background.

I'm using "**Try**" to get the value, however the value is caught on the first attempt. After downloading, if I press to try to get it again then it works.

**Note**: The progress bar also does not work on the first try.

**Image**

[image]

**What I have tried:**

```
Private Sub BWorkerD_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BWorkerD.DoWork

    Dim buffer(1023) As Byte
    Dim bytesIn As Integer
    Dim totalBytesIn As Integer
    Dim output As IO.Stream
    Dim flLength As Integer

    ''TRY TO GET FILE SIZE''

    Try
        Dim FTPRequest As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(txtFilePathD.Text), FtpWebRequest)
        FTPRequest.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(txtFTPUsernameD.Text, txtFTPPasswordD.Text)
        FTPRequest.Method = Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize

        flLength = CInt(FTPRequest.GetResponse.ContentLength)
        lblFileSizeD.Text = flLength & " bytes"

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    Try
        Dim FTPRequest As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(txtFilePathD.Text), FtpWebRequest)
        FTPRequest.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(txtFTPUsernameD.Text, txtFTPPasswordD.Text)
        FTPRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
        Dim stream As IO.Stream = FTPRequest.GetResponse.GetResponseStream
        Dim OutputFilePath As String = txtSavePathD.Text & "\" & IO.Path.GetFileName(txtFilePathD.Text)
        output = IO.File.Create(OutputFilePath)
        bytesIn = 1

        Do Until bytesIn < 1
            bytesIn = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)
            If bytesIn > 0 Then
                output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesIn)
                totalBytesIn += bytesIn
                lblDownloadedBytesD.Text = totalBytesIn.ToString & " bytes"
                If flLength > 0 Then
                    Dim perc As Integer = (totalBytesIn / flLength) * 100
                    BWorkerD.ReportProgress(perc)
                End If
            End If
        Loop

        output.Close()
        stream.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

''UPDATE EVERY PROGRESS - DONT WORK ON FIRST TRY''

Private Sub BWorkerD_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BWorkerD.ProgressChanged

    pBarD.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    lblPercentD.Text = e.ProgressPercentage & " %"
End Sub
```

Comment: First, try changing the line where you set the label text to `Invoke(Sub() lblFileSizeD.Text = flLength & " bytes")`. You're trying to access a label, which is owned by the GUI thread, from a background thread...so you may actually be getting a value back and just aren't able to see it. So try that change first, and let us know if you see anything. If you still don't, then at least it narrows the issue down a little more.

Comment: Thank you for the help, so... again, only works on the second try, when i click on download button again.

Comment: I just copied your code straight from the first "try" block, swapped in my own ftp credentials and path, and it worked perfectly...so I'm not really sure where else to look. Have you stepped through the code line by line?

Comment: I tried many things today, but nothing seems to work. After the download, if I press the button again, everything works. I dont understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problems (set `Option Strict On` to find more):
You can't access the UI objects from a thread different than the UI Thread.

The error you receive is:

> Cross-thread operation not valid:
> Control `lblFileSizeD` accessed from
> a thread other than the thread it was created on

Then, the same error for `lblDownloadedBytesD`.

Also, you are eating up your Error messages using an empty handler with:

```
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

This nullifies any *handling*, because there's none. You are simply letting the code  run past it without taking any action. The handlers are there to, well, handle the errors, not to let them go unchecked.

When you need to access and update some UI component property, use the `BackGroundWorker` [ReportProgress()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress) method. This method has an overload that accepts a parameter of type `Object`. Meaning, you can feed it anything. This Object will be the [e.UserState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.progresschangedeventargs.userstate) property in the `ReportProgress` [ProgressChangedEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.progresschangedeventargs) class.

The [.RunWorkerAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkerasync) method also accepts an Object parameter. This Object will become the [e.Argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.doworkeventargs.argument) property of the [BackgroundWorker.DoWork](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork) Event. This gives some flexibility in relation to the parameters you can actually pass to your `BackGroundWorker`.

One more problem: the Ftp Download procedure does not support cancellation. When run, a user can't stop it.

Last problem: as reported in the documentation, you should never reference the `BackGroundWorker` object you instantiated in your UI thread (the Form) in its `DoWork` event. Use the `sender` object and cast it to the `BackGroundWorker` class.

In this example, all the UI references are delegated to a Class object that is passed to the `DoWork` event through the `RunWorkerAsync(Object)` method (using the `e.Argument` property).
The Class object is updated with progress details and then fed to the `ReportProgress(Int32, Object)` method, which runs in the original Synchronization Context (the UI thread, where the `RunWorkerAsync` method is called).
The UI can be updated safely. No cross-thread operations can occur.

A cancellation method is also implemented. This allows to abort the download procedure and to delete a partial downloaded file, if one is created.

The error handling is minimal, but this is something you need to integrate with your own tools.

(I've used the same names for the UI Controls, it should be easier to test.)

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Security
Imports System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates

Public Class frmBGWorkerDownload

    Friend WithEvents BWorkerD As BackgroundWorker
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        BWorkerD = New BackgroundWorker()
        BWorkerD.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        BWorkerD.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True

        AddHandler BWorkerD.DoWork, AddressOf BWorkerD_DoWork
        AddHandler BWorkerD.ProgressChanged, AddressOf BWorkerD_ProgressChanged
        AddHandler BWorkerD.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf BWorkerD_RunWorkerCompleted
        BWorkerD.RunWorkerAsync(BGWorkerObj)
    End Sub

    Private Class BGWorkerObject
        Public Property UserName As String
        Public Property Password As String
        Public Property ResourceURI As String
        Public Property FilePath As String
        Public Property FileLength As Long
        Public Property DownloadedBytes As Long
        Public Property BytesToDownload As Long
    End Class

    Private Sub btnDownload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDownload.Click
        pBarD.Value = 0
        Dim BGWorkerObj As BGWorkerObject = New BGWorkerObject With {
            .ResourceURI = txtFilePathD.Text,
            .FilePath = Path.Combine(txtSavePathD.Text, Path.GetFileName(txtFilePathD.Text)),
            .UserName = txtFTPUsernameD.Text,
            .Password = txtFTPPasswordD.Text
        }
    End Sub

    Private Sub BWorkerD_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs)
        Dim BGW As BackgroundWorker = TryCast(sender, BackgroundWorker)
        Dim BGWorkerObj As BGWorkerObject = TryCast(e.Argument, BGWorkerObject)
        Dim FTPRequest As FtpWebRequest
        Dim BufferSize As Integer = 131072

        ' Windows 7 / Windows 10 lacking maintenance    
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

        FTPRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(BGWorkerObj.ResourceURI), FtpWebRequest)
        FTPRequest.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(BGWorkerObj.UserName, BGWorkerObj.Password)
        'FTPRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize
        '----------------------- UPDATE  ------------------------
        FTPRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails
        '--------------------- END UPDATE  ------------------------
        FTPRequest.EnableSsl = True

        '----------------------- UPDATE  ------------------------
        Using FtpResponse As WebResponse = FTPRequest.GetResponse, 
          DirListStream As Stream = FtpResponse.GetResponseStream(), 
          listReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(DirListStream)
            While Not listReader.EndOfStream
                Dim DirContent As String = listReader.ReadLine()
                If DirContent.Contains(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(BGWorkerObj.ResourceURI)) Then
                    BGWorkerObj.FileLength = Convert.ToInt64(DirContent.Split(New String() {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)(4))
                    BGW.ReportProgress(0, BGWorkerObj)
                    Exit While
                End If
            End While
        End Using
        '----------------------- END UPDATE  ------------------------

        'Using FtpResponse As WebResponse = FTPRequest.GetResponse
        '    BGWorkerObj.FileLength = Convert.ToInt64(FtpResponse.ContentLength)
        '    BGW.ReportProgress(0, BGWorkerObj)
        'End Using

        If BGW.CancellationPending Then e.Cancel = True

        Try
            FTPRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(BGWorkerObj.ResourceURI), FtpWebRequest)
            FTPRequest.EnableSsl = True
            FTPRequest.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(BGWorkerObj.UserName, BGWorkerObj.Password)
            FTPRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile

            Using Response As FtpWebResponse = DirectCast(FTPRequest.GetResponse, FtpWebResponse)
                If Response.StatusCode > 299 Then
                    e.Result = 0
                    Throw New Exception("The Ftp Server rejected the request. StatusCode: " &
                                        Response.StatusCode.ToString(),
                                        New InvalidOperationException(Response.StatusCode.ToString()))
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                Using stream = Response.GetResponseStream(), 
                  fileStream As FileStream = File.Create(BGWorkerObj.FilePath)
                    Dim read As Integer
                    Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(BufferSize - 1) {}
                    Do
                        read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                        fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, read)
                        BGWorkerObj.DownloadedBytes += read
                        BGWorkerObj.BytesToDownload = BGWorkerObj.FileLength - BGWorkerObj.DownloadedBytes

                        If BGW.CancellationPending Then
                            e.Cancel = True
                            Exit Do
                        Else
                            BGW.ReportProgress(CInt((CSng(BGWorkerObj.DownloadedBytes) / BGWorkerObj.FileLength) * 100), BGWorkerObj)
                        End If
                    Loop While read > 0
                End Using
            End Using

        Catch ex As Exception
            If e.Cancel = False Then Throw
        Finally
            If e.Cancel = True Then
                If File.Exists(BGWorkerObj.FilePath) Then
                    File.Delete(BGWorkerObj.FilePath)
                End If
            End If
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub BWorkerD_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs)
         pBarD.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
        lblPercentD.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() & " %"

        If lblFileSizeD.Text.Length = 0 Then
            lblFileSizeD.Text = CType(e.UserState, BGWorkerObject).FileLength.ToString("N0", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat)
        End If
        lblDownloadedBytesD.Text = CType(e.UserState, BGWorkerObject).DownloadedBytes.ToString("N0", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat)
        If e.ProgressPercentage <= 15 Then
            lblDownloadedBytesD.ForeColor = Color.Red
        ElseIf e.ProgressPercentage <= 66 Then
            lblDownloadedBytesD.ForeColor = Color.Orange
        Else
            lblDownloadedBytesD.ForeColor = Color.LightGreen
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub BWorkerD_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
        Dim DownloadAborted As Boolean = False
        If e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
            DownloadAborted = True
            lblDownloadedBytesD.ForeColor = Color.Red
            lblDownloadedBytesD.Text = "Error!"
        ElseIf e.Cancelled Then
            DownloadAborted = True
            lblDownloadedBytesD.ForeColor = Color.Yellow
            lblDownloadedBytesD.Text = "Cancelled!"
            pBarD.Value = 0
            lblPercentD.Text = "0%"
        Else
            lblDownloadedBytesD.ForeColor = Color.LightGreen
            lblDownloadedBytesD.Text = "Download completed"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAbortDownload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAbortDownload.Click
        BWorkerD.CancelAsync()
    End Sub
End Class
```

A visual result of the operation described:

[image: frmBGWorkerDownload Image]

[A PasteBin of the Form's Designer + Code](https://pastebin.com/Bjfyfmvh)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178742/discussion-between-sergio-wilker-and-jimi).