# Check if File Exists on FTP Server

Tags: vb.net, ftp

I found this code on the internet, but apparently it doesn't work. I don't know if the problem is my FTP Server...

Form

[image]

Code

```
Imports System.Net

Public Class Form1

    Dim ftpFile As String = "ftp://185.201.11.24/Team/ImersaStudios/Info.ini"
    Dim Username As String = "u171165696"
    Dim Password As String = "KU7KXW38"

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim request As FtpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(ftpFile)
        request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(Username, Password)
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize

        Dim response As FtpWebResponse

        Try
            response = request.GetResponse
            Label1.Text = "Found"

        Catch ex As WebException
            Label1.Text = "Not Found"
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: See the variables, I use on `request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential (Username, Password)`

Comment: Your server, for some reasons, doesn't respond well to a `FtpWebRequest` with `GetFileSize` as request method. Use `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory` using your remote file address as argument. You'll get a stream with a single line containing the file name only, if the file exists. [Use the code I already showed you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52007306/get-file-size-on-ftp-server-and-put-it-on-a-label?answertab=active#tab-top) (you could just use the exact same code) to get this information. It will also return the file size if the file is found.

Comment: Thanks again Jimi! Works well!

Comment: Don't worry Andrew, I intended to change the password! x)