# scrollbars of datagridview are blackened by backgroundWorker

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, backgroundworker, gdi

I have c# `WinForms` application, it has some search parameters (`TextBox` and `ComboBox`) and a search `Button`, below this `GroupBox` are two `DataGridView` controls placed side by side. Then I have a `PictureBox` placed on top of the `DataGridView` controls whose `Visible` property I have set to `False`. Then I also have a `BackgroundWorker`. On `button1_Click` event, I am setting `PictureBox's` `Visible` property to `True`and calling `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();`. On `backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e),` I am doing fetching records and populating `DataGridView` controls. On `backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e),` I am calling `pictureBox3.Hide();` **However, ever since I have added this *loader* functionality, the form remains unresponsive for some more seconds unlike the previous behavior and also the `ScrollBars` of the `DataGridView` controls are *blackened*. Like, literally *blackened*.** Though, `DataGridView` controls are still scrollable. The form itself has `DoubleBuffered` set to `True`. Also, I have made the `DataGridView` controls `DoubleBuffered` via `Reflection` like this,

```
public static void DoubleBuffered(this DataGridView dgv, bool setting)
        {
            Type dgvType = dgv.GetType();
            PropertyInfo pi = dgvType.GetProperty("DoubleBuffered",
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            pi.SetValue(dgv, setting, null);
        }
```

Please help me with the problematic (bold) part. Thank you.

> EDIT - `DoWork` Code

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
            dataGridView2.DataSource = null;
            if (btn2d.Checked && btn3d.Checked)
            {
                searchdata1();
                searchdata2();
            }
            if (!btn2d.Checked && !btn3d.Checked)
            {
                searchdata1();
                searchdata2();
            }
            if (btn2d.Checked && !btn3d.Checked)
            {
                searchdata1();
            }
            if (!btn2d.Checked && btn3d.Checked)
            {
                searchdata2();
            }
        }
```

Comment: The problem is probably generated in the DoWork method. If you Invoke() the UI thread each time you add a row to the DGV, your method becomes, in a way, synchronous. Also, you can't update the UI from the DoWork method. Use the [BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged) event, raised in the UI thread. You need to show how the code in the DoWork method operates, not how you set the `DoubleBuffered` property of a control (which, btw, works only if that control actually uses that property).

Comment: Jimi, please check the updated question. Also, btw, DoubleBuffered does work alright.

Comment: You *must* avoid referencing UI objects in the `DoWork` handler. No exceptions. Even the `BGW` itself. Cast `sender` to `BackGroundWorker` if you need to reference it. If you have to pass values to the `DoWork` method, use the object in `RunWorkerAsync(object)`. This object will become the `DoWorkEventArgs` parameter. First thing, move out of `DoWork` the `DataGridView.DataSource = null;`. These need to be set before calling  `RunWorkerAsync`. Use the `ReportProgress` method to perform any UI update (it will raise the `ProgressChanged` event, which is run on the UI thread).

Comment: Can I see an example of what you are saying?

Comment: You can find the same advices I gave you all over SO. I don't have a C# answer about the BackGroundWorker. It's not used that much in this language (Tasks/TPL are the major tools). I posted some in VB.Net. This one: [Get File Size on FTP Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52007306/get-file-size-on-ftp-server-and-put-it-on-a-label?answertab=active#tab-top) has a complete Form sample on PasteBin to test. It uses more or less all the features that I described here.