# How do i free up the parent UI when the progress bar invoked from the UI is performing background worker

Tags: vb.net, winforms, backgroundworker

I have a winform application which involves some processing work. While the task is in progress a progress bar is shown. The progress bar blocks the parent window from which the process is invoked. I want parent window UI to be free to do further work while the modal of progress bar is in progress. Currently backgroundworker is being used. What can be used to free up the UI?

Comment: *"I want parent window UI to be free to do further work while the modal of progress bar is in progress"*. That doesn't make sense. The whole point of a modal dialogue is to prevent access to the calling form. If you want to access the calling form then don't show a modal dialogue.  You probably need to call `Show(Me)`, to display a modeless dialogue AKA an owned form, instead of `ShowDialog` but it's hard to know what to change when we don't know what you currently have.  ALWAYS provide the relevant code.

Comment: @jmcilhinney As the application does heavy processing so the progress bar is there for long time therefore client wants that is should be minimised. And as the application is crucial and a legacy there's not much room for the modification.

Comment: A modal dialogue prevents what you're asking for by definition so, as long as you have a modal dialogue, you're out of luck.  Making the change I suggested may be all you need but it's impossible to say with so little information.  Give it a try and post back with specifics if it doesn't work.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Sure! :) Thanks for your help ! Really appreciate!

Comment: See an implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52007306/get-file-size-on-ftp-server-and-put-it-on-a-label?answertab=active#tab-top). The sample form can be downloaded from PasteBin (there's a link there).

Comment: @Jimi Thanks man :) Really helpful !

Comment: Add a StatusStrip and a ToolStripProgressBar. Make the StatusStrip not visible at design time and change that before and after the long-running code. Have a look at the link for ways of updating it -https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=update+toolstripprogressbar+%5Bvb.net%5D

Comment: Or create a new form that has a progress bar that can be updated from your main form