# How to create a progress bar that updates simultaneously with a file transfer

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar, file-transfer

As the title implies, I am trying to create a progress bar that updates with a file transfer. I am currently using Visual Studio 2019. I have been through dozens of articles and videos all claiming to do just this. After many days of testing, I have gotten close, but the progress bar will still only update after the file transfer is complete. I am using multi threading techniques to accomplish just this much. I would very much appreciate if someone could just lay it down for me on how to do this. Here is my code so far. It doesn't really help for making it but you can at least see what I am trying to achieve. I also left out some large chunks of commented out test script.

Summary of what I need to is: Create a script that will copy the specified directory and all sub directories. While doing this I would like the progress bar to move with the file transfer.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Threading
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub BtnStartTransfer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStartTransfer.Click
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Delegate Sub DelegateProgressBarMax(ByVal check As Integer)

    Private Sub ProgressBarUpdate(ByVal check As Integer)
        If pBar1.InvokeRequired = True Then
            Invoke(Sub() pBar1.Value = check)
        Else
            pBar1.Value = check
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Delegate Sub DelegateUpdateOutput(ByVal check2 As String)
    Private Sub OutputUpdate(ByVal check2 As String)
        If txtOutput.InvokeRequired = True Then
            Invoke(Sub() txtOutput.Text = txtOutput.Text & check2 & Environment.NewLine)
        Else
            txtOutput.Text = txtOutput.Text & check2
        End If
    End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        Dim getCopyFrom As String = txtCopyFrom.Text
        Dim getCopyTo As String = txtCopyTo.Text

        Dim splitUser() As String = getCopyFrom.Split("\")
        Dim finalValue As String = splitUser.Length - 1
        Dim stringValue As String = CStr(splitUser(finalValue))
        Dim getUser As String

        'If MsgBox("Is this the correct user?: " & stringValue, vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then
        '    getUser = stringValue
        'Else
        '    getUser = InputBox("Enter in the correct Username")
        'End If

        Dim checkCopyFrom As New IO.DirectoryInfo(getCopyFrom)
        Dim checkCopyTo As New IO.DirectoryInfo(getCopyTo)

        If checkCopyFrom.Exists Then

        Else
            MsgBox("The location you are trying to copy from does not exist.")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If checkCopyTo.Exists Then

        Else
            MsgBox("The location you are trying to copy to does not exist.")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Copying the Desktop folder
        Dim dirDesktop = getCopyFrom & "\Desktop"
        Dim getDir = IO.Directory.GetFiles(dirDesktop, "*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        Dim fileTotal As Integer = getDir.Length
        Dim filesTransferred As Integer = 0

        Dim di As New DirectoryInfo(dirDesktop)
        Dim fiArr As FileInfo() = di.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        Dim diArr As DirectoryInfo() = di.GetDirectories("*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        Dim fri As FileInfo
        Dim fol As DirectoryInfo

        For Each fri In fiArr
            filesTransferred += 1
            BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(CInt(filesTransferred * 100 \ fiArr.Length), True)
            OutputUpdate(fri.Name)
            'File.Copy(dirDesktop & "\" & fri.Name, getCopyTo & "\" & fri.Name, True)
            'My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(getCopyFrom & "\Desktop", getCopyTo & "\Users\" & getUser & "\Desktop", False)
        Next fri
End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
        pBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need delegates, just the `ReportProgress` method of the BackgroundWorker. See the example here: [Get File Size on FTP Server and put it on a Label](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52015773/7444103). In your case, you'll also have to decide if you want to update the progress for each file you copy (single progress bar) or also the copy progress of a single file (two progress bars, one for the current file and one for the overall progress). You should also include means a Cancel the operation.

Comment: @Jimi Yeah, I have been using the `ReportProgress` method, but it still only updates the progress bar after the file transfer finishes. And I don't need a progress bar for individual files, just one that updates with each file transferred and completing when the entire directory finishes transferring.

Comment: You code is not a working sample: i.e., you have this: `Dim getCopyFrom As String = txtCopyFrom.Text`. You cannot do that. Pass those values in the Object that will become `DoWorkEventArgs` when you start the BGW. See the overload of [BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkerasync) that allows to pass an object to the DoWork method.

Comment: You shouldn't show a MessageBox from a non-gui thread either.