# BackGroundWorker doesn't show percentage (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, background

When an upload is done in my application I would like to see the percentage. To avoid unexpected blockages the upload is done through a Background Worker. Unfortunately the percentage is not updated although I have declared that:

```
BackgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = True
```

This is my code:

```
 Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        My.Computer.Network.UploadFile(File, FtpAdress)
    End Sub

 Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    Label.Text = "Upload progress percentage: " + e.ProgressPercentage.toString + "%"
End Sub
```

the upload is done correctly but the percentage is not updated.
Sorry for my bad english and thank you if you will answer my question!

Comment: It's not automagic. You have to [ReportProgress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress) yourself when you feel like it. `My.Computer.Network.UploadFile` has its own interface, though. These classes belong to the .Net framework. No VBA involved.

Comment: Maybe you could try [WebClient.UploadFileAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadfileasync) (event-driven) or [WebClient.UploadFileTaskAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadfiletaskasync) (async/await pattern).

Comment: Check [FTP Upload, BackgroundWorker Progress Display](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?716679-RESOLVED-FTP-Upload-BackgroundWorker-Progress-Display), the _jmcilhinney's_ answer should solve your problem.

Comment: Ah, right, there's also FtpWebRequest, as @JQSOFT mentioned. I posted an example, using a BackgroundWorker with a ProgressBar, here: [Get File Size on FTP Server and put it on a Label](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52015773/7444103). There's also a sample Form - the one you see in the animation - that you can download and add to a project for testing.